# How do I add the "Text message" button to my personviewcontroller instances?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app uses personviewcontrollers, but when I display one, it does not have the same buttons "text message", etc, as the normal contacts app. Anyone know how to add those to the personviewcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for the allowsActions property, but this only exists on the [ABUnknownPersonViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABUnknownPersonViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: It does. I am new to iPhone development - and am a little confused. I have a tableview from which users tap and see an abpersonview. Are you saying that I need to use a difference view controller (abunknownpersonviewcontroller) INSTEAD of abpersonviewcontroller? Or do I use abunknownpersonviewcontroller as a subview?

Comment: Disclaimer: I have only played around with the AB*PersonViewControllers, so I am no expert. That said, you would use it instead of the regular ABPersonViewController.